# Как много времени приложения тратят приложения на разные процессы?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, запрос, архитектура

Может ли кто-нибудь дать информацию о том, сколько времени в общем тратит приложение (веб/декстоп не важно) на различные процессы? Возможно есть какие-то иследования, но я не нашла:(

Мое исследование направлено в основном на использование базы данных в информационных системах в соотношении к общему времени работы приложения. Но буду счастлива любой информации, которую вы мне посоветуете.
Возможно, некоторые диаграммы, научные исследования или из собственной практики.

Comment: Очевидно, что разные приложения тратят большую часть времени на разное. Одни на i/o, другие на расчеты, третьи на отрисовку, четвертые на сон. Для анализа конкретного приложения используют профилировщики, flame-graph, утилиты мониторинга.

Comment: Хм.... это от собственно процессов зависит. Есть короткие запросы к БД, типа вставки одной записи, выборки нескольких записей для отображения на экране, они проходят мгновенно и составляют думаю менее 0.1% от всего времени работы приложения. А может быть дают БД сложный запрос, аггрегирования данных за большой период времени, который выполняется несколько часов (если не дней) ...

Comment: см. так же термины OLTP / OLAP. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP